# How do I query Azure SQL elastic database utilization?

Tags: azure-sql-database

In the Azure Portal, under SQL Elastic Pools, I am able to obtain a list of databases in the pool together with the Peak EDTU, Avg EDTU, Size (GB) and Status.

How do I obtain this list via T-SQL, REST, Powershell, etc?

We have a large number of Azure SQL servers and elastic pools and I want a consolidated list of every database in the subscription together with it's EDTU utilization.

Answer (score 3):

There is no single query to get all the information that you are looking for. But you can get this information by combining few queries.

- You can use this [REST API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn505702.aspx) to list all servers in a subscription
- You can query this [REST API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt163646.aspx) to get a list of all databases in a server/elastic pool.
- you can query [sys.resource_stats](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn269979.aspx) DMV to get the list of all databases in that server along with their DTU utilization. Or use this [REST API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt163593.aspx) to get DTU usage for an individual database.

-- Srini

Answer (score 1):

There is no one single command to get the consolidated result of all the resources. You may need to use a PowerShell or T-SQL scripts for that.
But these are some of the many ways that may help you to build one.

#### DTU usage can be calculated directly by querying the db table.

##### eg. scripts for querying the master db for elastic pool eDTU usage.

```
     $sqlCommandForElasticPool=@"
        SELECT
            Top 1
            start_time, 
            end_time,
            (SELECT Max(v)
                    FROM (VALUES (avg_cpu_percent), (avg_data_io_percent), (avg_log_write_percent)) AS value(v)
                    ) AS [avg_DTU_percent]
        FROM sys.elastic_pool_resource_stats
        WHERE elastic_pool_name = '$ElasticPoolName' ORDER BY end_time DESC;
    "@
    $token =(Get-AzAccessToken -ResourceUrl "https://database.windows.net").Token
   
    $DBMetrics = Invoke-SqlCmd -Server "$ServerName.database.windows.net" -Database "master" -AccessToken "$token" -Query "$sqlCommandForElasticPool"
```

Please keep in mind that the querying client should have CONNECT permission on the db server.

If you are using a service principal for that this will help:

```
# Create the SP as an external user with CONNECT permission on server level
    $token =(Get-AzAccessToken -ResourceUrl "https://database.windows.net").Token
    $sqlCommandToCreateUser="CREATE USER [$ServicePrincipalName] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;"
    
    "Making Sp as an external user with CONNECT permission on server level"
    Invoke-SqlCmd -Server "$ServerName.database.windows.net" -Database "master" -AccessToken "$token" -Query "$sqlCommandToCreateUser"
```

##### You can also get the details with `AzMonitor` commands:

```
$monitorparameters = @{
    ResourceId = "/subscriptions/$($(Get-AzContext).Subscription.Id)/resourceGroups/$ResourceGroupName/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/$ServerName/elasticPools/$ElasticPoolName"
    TimeGrain = [TimeSpan]::Parse("00:01:00")
    MetricNames = "dtu_consumption_percent"
    }
    
    $MonitorMetrics = Get-AzMetric @monitorparameters -DetailedOutput
    
}
```

##### You can also directly query the azure monitor api using a HTTP request:

```
$request = "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/$SubscriptionId/resourceGroups/$ResourceGroupName/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/$ServerName/elasticpools/$ElasticPoolName/providers/microsoft.insights/metrics?metricnames=dtu_consumption_percent&timespan=$startDate/$endDate&interval=PT1M&aggregation=Average&top=3&orderby=Average desc&api-version=2019-07-01"
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $request -Method 'GET' -Headers $headers
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Azure Cli to get the details. The below example will get you the Standard elastic pool with 100 dtu's in West US:

```
az sql elastic-pool list-editions -l westus --edition Standard --dtu 100 --show-details db-min-dtu db-max-dtu db-max-size
```

Let me know if this helped.